Avalonia how to prevent a text box stop updating on every key press?
Avalonia synchronises view and view-model on every key press when using Text Box. This is sometimes quite useful! But I have an application where I'd like the "update" to happen only when I press the enter button or when I loose focus.
Is this possible in Avalonia?

At the time of writing, this is an upcoming feature you can only achieve in v.11.1 Preview.  You will set the UpdateSourceTrigger on the binding to LostFocus.
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />


Thanks! What about updating when the user presses the enter key, for example?

@DanielFarrell That's not typical behavior in any XAML based language.  Tab is the usual key for that.  However, if you want that to occur, you can always handle the key's event and make it happen.

Tab is fine. Users normally would press the enter key. Where do I file this bug to update my users?
